# KO option binding saving value as default when page reloads

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi i am using knockout to have a select drop-down bar to allow the user to select their location. Now due to the way my drop-down works it refreshes the page to bring in the correct products for that item.

What i want is to when the page refreshes to have the location they selected to be the default value in the dropdown. But at the moment it goes back to the optionCaption.

```
        <select id="SelectLocation" data-bind="options: OrgTitles, 
    optionsText: 'title', optionsCaption: 'Choose Centre...', 
value: StoreLocationSelected">
            </select>
```

Here is my JavaScript to refresh the page:

```
    StoreLocationSelected.subscribe(function () {
                        if (StoreLocationSelected() != undefined) {
                            var org = StoreLocationSelected().org;
                            var title = StoreLocationSelected().title;
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + 
window.location.host + org;
                        }

                    });
```

Is there anyway i can go about this? any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're refreshing the entire page once a selection is made then you're doing it wrong. Just make an ajax type request to get the information and update the existing page with the returned values, you shouldn't reload the entire page.

Have a method to fetch the data and call that via your subscription:

```
    viewModel.getData = function (someId) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://someurl/controller/getdata',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "Id": someId
            }               
        }).success(function (data) {
            viewModel.updateSomethingWithReturnedData(data);                
        });
    };
```

This would be done asynchronously, so you don't need to refresh the page. Once a knockout observable has it's value changed via `viewModel.updateSomethingWithReturnedData(data);`, the page will be updated.